# coordinator layout custom scroll behavior

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-coordinatorlayout, custom-scrolling

I have a layout where i use coordinator layout to collapse appbarlayout to a toolbar when user scroll on the screen.

The default behaviour is quite accurate but problems show up when the user clicks on an edit text field, once the softkeyboard shows up, the screen is pushed up ( i use the flag "adjust resize on my activity) and the appbar layout is off the screen.

What i want to achieve is :

- collapse the appbar layout to toolbar when user scrolls (i already have this implemented)
- collapse the appbar layout to toolbar whenever the soft keyboard is shown.

Is this possible?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to collapse `AppBarLayout` when the `Soft Keyboard` is shown, you can follow these two steps:

1- Use this library to detect soft keyboard visibility events:
    https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent

2- When the soft keyboard opens, use this method to collapse your `AppBarLayout`:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

Example:

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
    getActivity(),//Or context
    new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
            if(isOpen){
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
            }
        }
    });
```